# Kotlin "Any type that implements an interface"

Tags: kotlin

I have a delegate interface:

```
interface Delegate {
    fun didSelectWord(word: String)
}
```

And I would like to have a property called `delegate`

```
val delegate: <T> where T : Delegate
```

the `delegate` can be anything that implements Delegate

I have also tried

```
val delegate: Any : Delegate
```

But both give compile error

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot it's a very common approach in objective-c/swift. There should be something similar for kotlin

Comment: I was mistaking. You can see my full explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy

```
val delegate: Delegate
```

Now something like this works

```
interface Delegate

class Test: Delegate {
    fun yourMethod() = "Your Method" 
}

fun test() {
    val delegate: Delegate

    delegate = Test()

    println(delegate)
}
```

If you want to use a function that is only present in `Test`, but not in `Delegate`, you have to cast it

```
(delegate as Test).yourMethod()
```

Otherwise only functions that are present in `Delegate` will work

`delegate.yourMethod()` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
class SomeClass<T : Delegate> {

     val delegate: T = // initialize delegate ...
}
```

Make the `class` a generic type that declares the type parameter `T`. And you can create properties of type `T`.